# How can I avoid mid-link word wrap with CSS?

Tags: css

I have a list of items displayed horizontally for my navigation area, but it's wrapping mid-link, like this

```
| This is Item One | This is Item Two | This is Item Three | This is
Item Four | This is Item Five |
```

when I want it to wrap like this:

```
| This is Item One | This is Item Two | This is Item Three  
| This is Item Four | This is Item Five |
```

I tried using the `whitespace: nowrap` declaration on my link items (li a), but that just makes the second (wrapped) line disappear entirely.

Comment: Post your code, so we can see, what you tried

Comment: If you addition had any effect, you must have spelled the property name `white-space` right. If the effect was what you describe, then the mess was caused by something on the page that you did not describe at all.

Answer (score 17):

I believe what you are looking for is the [white-space property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

```
.menu a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Another option would be to assign a fixed width and float each menu item to the left.

```
.menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Of course, the CSS will vary depending on your HTML. I'd recommend putting you menu in an unordered list, and applying these styles to the list items.

Comment: Mnemonic: "white" and "space" are spaced by a hyphen, "nowrap" won't wrap.

Comment: Though you did link to w3schools :( That just encourages people to believe what they read at w3schools.

Comment: Jon, you are commenting on an answer, not the original question. Both the answer and the link get the property name right.

Comment: @JonHanna Oh, can you point out the errors in that W3Schools page?

Comment: No, that just makes things worse. If we keep linking to w3schools when they're correct, it makes people treat them as a resource.

Comment: @JonHanna Meh. I don't hate W3Schools. They don't have more errors than many other "html tutorial" sites I could mention, so I don't know why people keep on singling out W3Schools as a target for their hatred. Not saying they're flawless; I did find an error on that page...

Comment: @MrLister because people keep treating them as a resource and their "certification" as meaningful. Compare with SO: I say something someone thinks incorrect (it happens), comment objects, I either concede, refute or at least the debate is visible. W3Schools might fix something if the criticism on w3fools.com was particularly sarcastic, after a few years. SO makes the web better, W3Schools fills it full of more bullschildt. "Teach a man to fish"; linking to w3s is like taking a man who could fish, and wiping that part of their brain. It's not like the actual spec isn't on the web.

Comment: Did not work for me, because it blocked wrapping in entire paragraph

Comment: There are a few comments here on the quality of the documentation on w3schools.com. I would like to point out that this criticism is really outdated, and even w3fools.com admits that. Of course, any website contains errors, but these days w3schools.com doesn't seem to be worse than anybody else.

Answer (score 8):

Without having any of your styles and markup at my disposal, this is the best that I can offer for a solution (as it's a wild guess to what your problem is exactly):

All you need to do is apply `display:inline-block` to the appropriate `<a>` tags.

Comment: This is nice, since it also prevents wrapping after hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

*I realize this is an old question, but since an answer was never accepted, here's an answer in today's context:*

Nowadays, you can work around this by setting the parent to `display: flex` and applying the `white-space: nowrap` to the children.  The flex layout handles wrapping of the group of links, and the links themselves are prevented from having their words wrap.

```html
<div class="link-group">
  <a class="link">First Link</a>
  <a class="link">Second Link</a>
  <a class="link">Third Link</a>
  <a class="link">Fourth Link</a>
</div>
```

```css
/* parent */
.link-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* child */
.link {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```